# Having Max Clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I am looking to get the maximum date from table B and I am not understanding the error.  I am a SAS programmer and new to SQL.

```
select a.*
    , b.ZIP_CD
    , b.date
from DataA              as a
    left join DataB     as b    on a.name = b.name
group by a.name
having max(b.date) = b.date
```

Error message is:

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Column 'Datab.Date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery (or similar technique):

```
select a.*, b.ZIP_CD, b.date
from DataA a join
     DataB b  
     on a.name = b.name
where b.date = (select max(b2.date) from DataB b2 where b2.name = b.name);
```

This is not an aggregation query.

By the way, if you need the maximum value, then you are looking for an `inner join`.  If you still want to keep values of `a` that are not in `b`, then:

```
select a.*, b.ZIP_CD, b.date
from DataA a join
     DataB b  
     on a.name = b.name and
        b.date = (select max(b2.date) from DataB b2 where b2.name = b.name);
```